# how to connect a blade with helper in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to connect a blade with an helper because i want to get "name" of HTML form field and use this "name=amount" in helper .
i tried to use request to get amount in helper but did not work.
is there any way to call name amount  from HTML form  to helper

i tried :

```
$request->amount
```

here is helper function code:

how i can see where is definattion of $deposit_amount

```
function updateDepositBV($id, $deposit_amount)
{
    while($id !="" || $id != "0") {
        if(isMemberExists($id))
        {
            $posid = getParentId($id);
            if($posid == "0")
                break;
            $position = getPositionParent($id);
            $currentBV = MemberExtra::where('user_id', $posid)->first();

            if($position == "L"){
                $new_lbv = $currentBV->left_bv + $deposit_amount ;
                $new_rbv = $currentBV->right_bv;
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, can you show how you tried to use `$request`?

Comment: the  main problem is i want to check from where  $deposit_amount is defined

Comment: how about `request()->input('amount')` ?

Comment: You didn't answer either of my questions though :)

Comment: can i  get name = amount directly from blade to helper.php

Comment: LARAVEL 5.5.33  VERSION

Comment: request()->input('amount') worked

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access submitted form data inside a controller method you would use the `Request` class to get this.

There are a few different ways you can access the request object:

**Dependency Injection**

To do this you add an argument to method with `Request` as the type hint:

```
function updateDepositBV(Request $request ,$id, $deposit_amount)
```

You will also need to import the request at the top of the class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Laravel will then automatically resolve this for you.

---

**Helper Function**

Instead of using dependency injection you can also just use the `request()` helper function to resolve the request.

Then to access the information from the form you can use the `input()` method on the request e.g.

```
$request->input('amount');
```

or

```
request()->input('amount'); //or just request('amount')
```

Or in most circumstances you will be able to just access the name as a property on the request (`$request->amount`), however, this may not always work as you may have a collision between one of your form input names and an actual property on the request class.

For more information please look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input)

Answer (score 1):

```
request()->input('amount')
```

worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can call helper function from blade like

```
{{App\updateDepositBV(2,2340)}}
```

where 2 as your $id and 2340 as your $deposit_amount

Answer (score 0):

`request()->get('amount');` will work as well